# Sexy.alert from C#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, alert, code-behind

i'm using a jQuery plugin named SexyAlertBox (http://www.coders.me/ejemplos/sexy-alert-box/)

This is working: `<input type="button" id="btnHello" onclick="Sexy.alert('Hello!');" />`

But i need to call this function from the code behind file too. Usually i use this:

```
    protected void btnError_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "miscript", "alert('This is an alert from a postback!');", true);   
    }
```

But isn't working with the Sexy.alert function.

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: What a stupid name for a plugin.

Comment: So wouldn't you just need to make sure your plugin is loaded first and change `alert` to `Sexy.alert`?

Comment: Maybe don't use this script. The site says the script is outdated and there is a new version. Follow that link and you get a commercial product. How about http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, do not use that plugin. Just go with [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts).